# chosing a correct client technology for a new project (box editor)

Tags: flash, apache-flex, html

I need to develop a new tool, shall we call it box editor: a user can add/remove boxes and add/remove connections between boxes, the user can also edit interior of boxes. Box editor should be something like editor [here](http://didreseller.com/) (see video).

The thing I'm worrying about is to chose correct technologies. Here are my questions.

1. Do I understand correctly that for animation of objects (for my box editor) MXML+AS3 is not an option? Is Flash (I mean AS3 without mxml) more convenient tool for my purposes?
2. HTML5 is geting very popular now. Still, I'm not very strong in HTML5. Will it be hard to write something like provided example in HTML5? Is HTML5 a better choise then Flash for  that? Anyway, it will be nice to see an example of doing something like box editor in example with HTML5.

Please note that future app do not need to be launched on mobile devices. So 'there's no Flash on iPad' is not very strong argument here!

Thank you in advance! And please dont be shy, any thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: As many will tell you; StackOverflow is not a recommendation engine.  I voted to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I understand correctly that for animation of objects (for my box
>   editor) Flex is not an option? Is Flash (I mean AS3 without mxml) more
>   convenient tool for my purposes?

No, you do not.  Flex is a framework built on top of AS3.  AS3 is the language of Flash (and AIR).  Anything you can do in plain AS3 you can do in Flex; including animation.  Flex provides some transitions and effect classes, but you can also write your own or use ones others have written.

```
Please note that future app do not need to be launched on mobile devices. So 'there's no Flash on iPad' is not very strong argument here!
```

If you want a browser based app to run on the iPad, then you can't use Flash/Flex/AS3.  However, you can use Flex/Flash/AS3 technology to create a native iOS app.